# How to use environment variables in React?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

```r
process.env.VARIABLE_NAME
```

This does not work for some reason. It works in node after configuration the `dotenv` library.

What do I need to do in the react side to make it work?

Comment: have you read this? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `dotenv` in React only for variables that start with `REACT_APP_`.

So,

```
// index.js
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY) //works
console.log(process.env.DB_USER) //does not work
```